bean injections when testing quarkus applicaiton
We have a Quarkus+vertx application (written on java) and we want to test a few specific services from it, specifically classes annotated with
@ApplicationScoped
@Startup 

There is MainService class and there are some other SecondaryService classes which implement specific  Secondary interface. Each of these SecondaryService classes have a @Postconstruct method that puts the service in a map which is used in MainService  and makes a request to fetch some data.
I don't want to start Quarkus application with all of its context as there are a lot of other services and verticles that we don't need for this test.
So i am looking for a way to inject only MainService and all of SecondaryService (more precice all classes that implement Secondary interface)
Because i don't want all Quarkus with all its context to start, i am not using @QuarkusTest annotation. I tried to use @QuarkusComponentTest  and inject services as follows
@Inject
MainService mainService;

@Inject
List<Secondary> secondaryServices;

But seems that services are not injected. I don't get to init or @PostConstruct of any of these services.
Also the amount of implementations of Secondary is changing. Sometimes we add new ones and sometimes we remove some so injecting them one by one is not a robust option.
is there a way when testing quarkus to inject only specific services without starting the whole application?

@Inject List<Secondary> doesn't do what you want, you need @Inject @All List<Secondary>.

tried that as well, didn't work :(

That sounds wrong. Could you put together a small reproducer and file a bug? Thanks!

And what about @Inject Instance ?

And if Im not wrong, @QuarkusComponentTest mocks Secondary services, so they don’t get initialised.

Serkan,
I am very new to the whole testing thing. Could you clarify what does
'QuarkusComponentTest mocks Secondary services, so they don’t get initialised.' mean?
That it won't work? That i need to use @InjectMock annotation? Or how do i initialize these services?

@Ladicek
I created a simple project that shows the problem: https://github.com/dasha-klim/quarkus_test.git.
In test class none of the postconstract methods are called and list with Secondaries is empty. Could you check and let me know if i am missing something or its a bug. Thank you.
